# Validating rails input field to be numeric.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, view

If I have a rails field like:

```
    <div class="field form-group">
        <%= f.label :x_size, class: 'col-sm-1 control-label' %>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <%= f.text_field :x_size, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How would I validate the submit button to work only on numeric inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`number_field`

[Docs here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/number_field)